# how to find the sql string being passed to hive table from spark apis like filter

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am facing issues due to length of string being passed to hive table when I form a filter query.
Something like:

```
val filtered = df.filter(col("name").isin(list))
```

now when I do filter.show it fails as it hits the char limit of 2500 characters.

**What I want to find is** : given filtered dataframe, how to know what query in form of string will be passed internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect this in the execution plan: `filtered.explain()`